# Are linear dyamical systems $\dot{x}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$ considered autonomous ODEs or nonautonomous ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have a confusion about whether linear dynamical systems $\dot{x}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$ are considered autonomous ODEs or nonautonomous. My confusion comes from the input term $Bu(t)$.

The main thing that I want to do is to use this [dissertation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/methods/methods-ode/Niesen2004.pdf) to calculate the global discetization error of linear dynamical systems. This dissertation considers the general nonautonomous ODEs of the form $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$ (on the page 7) with a given initial condition.

The only mentioned requirement of $f(x,t)$ is that f must be Lipschitz continuous on the domain of $x$ for all t.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your DEFINITION of "autonomous" ODE?

Comment: I think an autonomous ODE is an ODE where we do not have any part that is a function on $t$ on the right-hand side except for the $x$ (state). I am not even sure if linear dynamical systems are non-autonomous since we have $Bu$.

Comment: It depends on $u(t)$. If for example $u(t)=-Kx(t)$ then the system is autonomous. Same if $u(t)=5$ for example. However if $u(t)=t$ then its nonautonomous. So you can't really tell before choosing what $u$ means. If not specified you have to assume it is nonautonomous as thats the more general setting.

Answer (score 2):

Your right hand side depends both on $x$ and $t$, so your system is not autonomous. In general, autonomous means that the evolution from a given state $x$ only depends on that state, but in your case it also depends on the value of $u$ at the given $t$.

Comment: Can we conclude that it is non-autonomous?

Comment: Correct.  There is an explicit dependence on $t$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!